# Sending a variable to mysql

Tags: android, json

I want to send the `Id_student` variable to MySQL but face to the following exception:

> org.json.JSONException: Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be
>   converted to JSONArray

I have attached my code as following:

```
int id_student=123;

String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL ="http://pharamjo.96.lt/Select/ImageJsonData.php?";

    String JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME = "Id_student";
    String JSON_IMAGE_URL = "Url";



    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);

        GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

        JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();

        //show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show);


        /*Intent intent = getIntent();
        id_student = intent.getStringExtra("student");
        //show.setText(id_student);*/


    }

 public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL + id_student ,


                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("Select", "onResponse");

                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("********Select********",error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

 public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));

                GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
        }

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
```

Would you please guide me to solve my problem?

Comment: please post your stacktrace, not just the topline

Comment: with the url that you have posted it is returning `0 results`  what query string does it expect?

Comment: if ($result->num_rows >0) {

 // output data of each row
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);


 }

} else {
 echo "0 results";

}

Comment: You are not sending a variable to MySql but to a Php ... So, you post the full Android code but you don't notice that you received `0 results` as expected in you php. So this is where you have a problem. PS : your query will look like `http://pharamjo.96.lt/Select/ImageJsonData.php?123`, you should add a key to that value